# How to return to the main application when done clicked from calendar(default)?

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentprovider

Is there any method to close the calendar application when "done" is pressed and return to the main application?
I think startActivityForResult(intent, int) can be used, but i'm not clear about how to use it.
This is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("title", header);
    intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTimeStamp);
    intent.putExtra("endTime", endTimeStamp);
    intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
    intent.putExtra("description", note);
    FragmentCaller.removeFragment(getActivity());
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this code in first Activity :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == 1) {

     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
         String result=data.getStringExtra("result");          
     }

  }
}//onActivityResult
```

and in second Activity this :

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("result",result); // u wanna return data
 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
 finish();
```